Add size legend to plotly.express.scatter_mapbox
I have a visualization done using plotly.express.scatter_mapbox. It basically shows the different institutions on the Saudi Arabia map. These institutions are marked by small circles that are color coded to reflect the category this institution belongs to. There are 4 main categories and the legend for these was automatically generated. Now, the size of the markers (circles in this case) reflects the count of publications made by an the institutions. So, if we have an institution with a lot of publications, then the marker would be much larger compared to another that has much less publications.
The problem is that I only have a legend to explain the different colors of the markers. I do not have one to explain the different sizes of the markers. Ideally, I would like to have one that would explain the different sizes on a scale. Worst case scenario, a one line explaining that the size reflects the publication count would be acceptable as well.
I have checked the documentation here for some way of modifying the function attributes but could not find anything.
Edit:
Each row in my data represents an institution in Saudi Arabia. I have the Latitude and Longitude columns representing the coordinates of the institutions in Saudi. I also have a Cluster column that indicates which of the 4 clusters does the institution belong to. Finally, I have a pub_counts column that represent the number of publications made by each institution in the dataset.
Here is part of the data i am using:
data
Here is my code
if plot_map == True:
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers.default='browser'

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(Institutes_SA, 
                        lat="Latitude", lon="Longitude", 
                        hover_name="institution_name", 
                        mapbox_style= "carto-positron", 
                        #"carto-darkmatter", 
                        zoom=4.5,
                        width = 1075,
                        height = 900,
                        color = 'Cluster',
                        color_discrete_sequence=['red','green','orange','DodgerBlue'],
                        size='pub_counts',
                        size_max = 40,
                        opacity=0.5
                        )

pio.show(fig)


Can you add to the question the data you are using and the current output graph? If you can't add data, toy data would be fine. Also, have you reviewed what the reference explains about the legend size? Try this: fig.update_layout(legend= {'itemsizing': 'trace'})

thanks for replying. I added a description of the data as well as the code I am using.

I customized the examples in the reference based on the data in the updated question. Where modified, we created a dictionary with mapped categories and colors. This was done for the marker colors. There was no publication number in the data column provided, so we changed it to a different column. Running this code will create multiple legends for the same category. This is to answer your request. To distinguish the same marker size, create a list of categories as in the legend and add them to the legend name (name). Finally, this scattergeo does not allow you to draw detailed maps such as mapbox.
import plotly.graph_objects as go

category_dict = {'Hospitals & Health Centers': 'red', 'Societies & Gov Bodies': 'green','Universities & Colleges': 'orange', 'other': 'DodgerBlue'}
scale = 5000

fig = go.Figure()

for row in Institutes_SA.itertuples():
    mcolor = category_dict[row.Cluster]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
        lon=[row.Longitude],
        lat=[row.Latitude],
        text=row.work_counts,
        marker=dict(
            size=row.work_counts/scale,
            color=mcolor,
            sizemode='area'
        ),
        name=row.Cluster
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    title_text = 'Publications by institution',
    height=500,
    showlegend = True,
    # margin={"r":0,"t":30,"l":0,"b":0},
    geo = dict(
        fitbounds="locations",
        center=dict(
            lon=Institutes_SA.Longitude.mean(),
            lat=Institutes_SA.Latitude.mean()
        ))
    )
fig.show()



Yes, it does seem that this choice is particularly limited with respect to the variety of option offered. It seems that I need to look for something else. Would you recommend another library to add a label to explain the size of the circles, please?

It depends on what you want to do with the visualization. That is for you to decide. The following code is the key to distinguishing the legend. limits = [(0,3),(3,11),(11,21),(21,50),(50,3000)];name = '{0} - {1}'.format(lim[0],lim[1])))
